# Keeping Kendo Datepicker in min/max range

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When a user types to type in a date outside of the range, we're trying to ensure the date gets changed to the closest min/max. The text displayed in the date picker does not change though even thought the script is changing the value()

```
@(Html.Kendo()
  .DatePickerFor(x => x.DOB)
  .Max(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).Year, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).Month, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).Day))
  .Min(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-70).Year, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-70).Month, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-70).Day))
  .Events(e=>e.Change("onDOBChange"))
  .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required", ng_model = "model.DOB" }))

<p ng-show="validateState.submitted && frmMain.DOB.$invalid" class="help-block">Please select</p>
  <script>
    function onDOBChange(e) {
      var dt = $("#DOB").data("kendoDatePicker");
      if (dt.value() < dt.min()) {
        dt.value(dt.min());
      } else if (dt.value() > dt.max()) {
        dt.value(dt.max());
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the dt.min() and dt.max() in JavaScript Date() initializers like:  dt.value(new Date(dt.min())); and dt.value(new Date(dt.max());  Kendo is probably expecting a JS Date object and your min() and max() may not be JS Date objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution, check for null in the val() and then go to the element to get it out:

http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/AtUl